# command restriction in container Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-container

I want to create a container with the command line arguments **--lines 56 -F** .

1. option: For this purpose I ran the command =>  **`k run app --image=lfccncf/arg-output --dry-run=client -o yaml > pod9.yaml`**

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     labels:
       run: app
     name: app
   spec:
     containers:
     - image: lfccncf/arg-output
       name: app
       args: ["--lines","56","F"]
   ```
2. option: Here is the second option how to accomplish the task.
   **`kubectl run app1 --image=lfccncf/arg-output --dry-run=client --command ["--lines 56 -F"] -o yaml > pod9.yaml`**

I have this restriction "When creating your pod you do not need to specify a container command, only args". Which option is correct with the mentioned restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 1 since you are saying that you don't need to specify the command and that assumes it's already pre-baked into the container image. `--lines 56 -F` are arguments and not 'the command'

Quoted from the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-podhttps://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod):

> The command and arguments that you define in the configuration file override the default command and arguments provided by the container image. If you define args, but do not define a command, the default command is used with your new arguments.

A similar working approach would be:

```sh
$ kubectl run app1 --image=lfccncf/arg-output --dry-run=client -o yaml -- --lines 56 -F > pod9.yaml
```